# How do I add a way for members to join/Log in and have profiles to my website if my SQL server doesn't have the option for more than the one database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I was looking into how to add a create user account/login to my website, so I could have members join and come back, etc and ended up finding out in order to do that, I'd need to create a new database in my SQL, to store the users credentials, I dont have the option to create any new databases by my webhost. Only the one database is what I can use. Could I just add this to my existing database? Do I really need more than 1 database on SQL for my website? If so, could I add another SQL server direct on my computer and use both, Mine and the web host one where I'm creating the site to manage my website? Im sorry for the few questions, Im really new to all this and so confused and overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple tables in same database.just make a table with fields such as user id,password etc. and use it for saving,fetching user details using sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Could I just add this to my existing database?**

Yes, you can tables to the existing database.

**Do I really need more than 1 database on SQL for my website?**

There are a lot of websites that use just one database. Some websites use connections to multiple databases. What information is stored in which database is frequently the result of factors *other* than the website. The ability to connect to multiple databases means that a website could use authentication/authorization info from one database, store user profiles and submissions in another, and read information from other sources (for example, historical stock prices, stored in another database.

All of that information could be stored in a single database. Having them as separate databases means that the databases can be managed separately (frequencye of backups, replication to DR site) and makes it easier to share the database across multiple applications. (For example, we would probably want employee payroll and health care information stored in a separate database, with separate access controls.

**Could I add another SQL server direct on my computer and use both, Mine and the web host one where I'm creating the site to manage my website?**

It may be technically possible to do that, but that's not the way you want to go. That would add another dependency... the website at the web hosting provider would be dependent on having access to another database, which is not being backed up and managed along with your website.

Comment: Thank you. Could I just add the file needed( I guess, a txt file) to my one database or do I need to create a new one for that because like i said my web host doesn't allow new database to be created?